# How can i remove Nodes of Manifest-File created with Mage.exe/MageUI.exe without getting trouble with the namespace?

Tags: c#, xml

In the Last few Days i tried to `.Remove();` some Nodes in a Manifest-File , to specify the Problem i tried to delete the Populated-Files in a [Manifest-File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632(v=vs.85).aspx) with a C# programm.

If you don't know exactly what a Populated file is i will explain it as good as i can:

A Populated File is a File (example: "Populated-File.txt.deploy") wich one you need for you're [Manifest-File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632(v=vs.85).aspx), because without Populated-Files your Application won't do that much. When you press the "Populate"-Button in the [MageUI.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.110).aspx) or you set the Option "-FromDirectory" in the [Mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx) you will add Nodes in the [Manifest-File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632(v=vs.85).aspx), they are called `<dependency dependencyType="install"></dependency>` and `<file></file>`. In these Nodes are Informations about the Populated-Files(example: name="Populated-File.txt.deploy" size="123" location="..."and so on).

These Nodes are in the [Manifest-File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632(v=vs.85).aspx) just like that:

Attention should be paid to the 2nd Node : `<asmv1:assembly>`, because that is default if the [Manifest-File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632(v=vs.85).aspx) got created with [MageUi.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.110).aspx)/ [Mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx), there  starts the Problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
<asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="Example.exe" />
  <description asmv2:iconFile="Example.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />

<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" size="123">
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

 <file name="PopulatedFile.dll.deploy" size="123">
 </file>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

After a while I got it, with some help from this Forum.

```
   //does currently only delete the "<dependency></dependency>"-Node
xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install").Select(x => x.Parent).Remove();
xml.Save(filePath);
```

So far so good, but as i added `.Remove();` for the `<file></file>`-Node that the Code looked like that:

```
xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install").Select(x => x.Parent).Remove();
xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "file").Remove();
xml.Save(filePath);
```

I noticed that the [Manifest-File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632(v=vs.85).aspx) has added, infront of almost every Node, `asmv2:` and  the `<dependency>`-Nodes got deleted. It would be better when `<dependency>`/`<file>`-Nodes get deleted and there would be any `asmv2`.

Just like that:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
 <asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="Example.exe" />
  <description asmv2:iconFile="Example.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />

  <asmv2:file name="PopulatedFile.dll.deploy" size="123">
  </asmv2:file>

  </asmv1:assembly>
```

The consiquence is that the File is not openable anymore with [MageUi.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.110).aspx).

So i started to research also on this Forum, and got as answer its the Namespace.
`xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"`

So finally:
My question is How could i solve this?

As always: You can edit this so it gets more specific or even more correnct (maybe i didn't explained the Populate-Files right)
Please correct me in any way but be constructive :)

Comment: Oh @JonSkeet i tried to follow ure instructions about writing a good question :)

Comment: It would help if you'd write in normal English, with "you" instead of "u", "your" instead of "ure" etc. This isn't texting. But it's much better than the previous questions.

Comment: oh im sorry its just i normally text like this (i know it's bad :/)

Comment: It's one thing to send mobile text messages like that (although personally I don't) - but it's very off-putting to read in "normal" text. The more readable you can make your questions, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like LINQ to XML is getting confused because the namespace is declared twice in the root element - once as the default namespace, and once with an alias of `asmv2`. The simplest solution is just to remove that attribute.

To be honest, MageUI *should* cope with it anyway - it's representing the right data. Yet another program that doesn't look at the XML properly, apparently. (Sigh...)

I'd also look for descendants with the right name (in the right namespace) rather than looking for a particular `LocalName`. For example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
doc.Root.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "asmv2").Remove();
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2";
doc.Descendants(ns + "dependentAssembly")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install")
   .Select(x => x.Parent)
   .Remove();
doc.Descendants(ns + "file").Remove();
doc.Save("test2.xml");
```

Output (reformatted a little):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd"
   manifestVersion="1.0"
   xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
   xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
   xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" 
   xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
   xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="Example.exe" />
  <description p8:iconFile="Example.ico"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
    xmlns:p8="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" />
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: Maybe i didn't said it clear enough but i also try to delete the `<file>`-Nodes. Is `xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "file").Select(x => x.Parent).Remove();` ok for that?

Comment: @Gentle: Well no, that's trying to remove the *parents* of the file elements, and it's looking for ones not in a namespace. (Read the code!) I've edited my answer to include code to do that.

Comment: thank you for answering all of my Questions :) you really helped me out :) and you're always kind. Thanks :)